# Generating large number of correlated variables with copulas

Tags: copula

I need to generate a lot of correlated variables (at least $9000$). I have been using Gaussian copula so far and it seems to be working fine. However, Gaussian copula is tail independent which can be a concern.

The other option is using pair copula constructions (PCCs). But from what I understand, this might require a lot of assumptions regarding the structure of conditional independence and choosing the order might be difficult as well. Are PCCs suitable for generating so many variables?

Would Gaussian copula be good enough considering it is much more convenient in dealing with so many variables?

Comment: There are other possibilities besides those you mention (such as a t-copula for example).

Comment: You can use PCC with only Gaussian copula. However, construct vine with this high number is really complicated.

Comment: That is what I thought as well. I am thinking of using Gaussian and rely on Student's t to allow for some amount of tail dependence. Thanks for your responses!